# I want to post an SOAP envelope via windows

Tags: windows, web-services, http

I am searching for a tool that sends an SOAP message to a server and works in windows.

No soapUI or WebServiceStudio. Something simple like curl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a SOAP message is only an XML file, wget should be what you are looking for. It can be used like this:

```
wget http://yourserver/endpoint --post-file=your_message.xml
```

You can download it from [here](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages.html)